# C++11 , leaking memory

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, memory, instruments

I have a case which the instrument of Xcode detected

```
std::vector<UserID_t> functions::getUserIds() const {
    static_assert(sizeof(int64) == sizeof(uint64_t), "size is not matched");
    auto object = AAAAA::BBBB::ValueObject<int64 *>(_hash->getValue((nByte)Key::USER_IDS));
    auto size = object.getSizes();
    std::vector<UserID_t> ret(*size);
    auto pVal = object.getDataCopy();
    for (int index = 0; index < *size; index++) {
        ret[index] = *pVal;
        ++pVal;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The tool shows me that the elements in "ret" are not released after return.
But I think int64 is a scalar variable, I don't need to release them.
Is that right?

I use Xcode 6.3.2

Comment: The fact that `object.getSizes()` returns a pointer is suspicious. What does this pointer point to? What's the lifetime of the pointee? Similar questions with `object.getDataCopy()`

Comment: yes , `object.getSizes()` return a pointer .  the timeline of pointer just only in this functions. I can't find `Similar questions with object.getDataCopy()` , could you link it to topic , many thanks

Comment: @KenjyNeo: You misunderstood the comment about `getDataCopy`, Igor just wanted to say that he had similar questions about `getDataCopy` that he asked about `getSizes`. I recommend that you edit your post to either: remove `auto` and put the real types OR show the declaration of all `typedef` and functions involved, namely: what are `UserID_t`, `Key::USER_IDS`, `getValue`, `ValueObject`, `getSizes`, `getDataCopy`? Without those elements, would be answerers can only guess at your issue.

Comment: It's clear what the lifetime of the *pointer* is. The question is, what's the lifetime of the *pointee*? How are `getSizes()` and `getDataCopy()` implemented? Do they allocate memory on the heap, and expect the caller to deallocate it (note that you don't)? If not, then who allocates the memory, and who's responsible for deallocating it?

Comment: @MatthieuM , @ Igor Tandetnik : the type of `UserID_t`  is `uint64_t `, 'getSizes' is `const short *`,` getDataCopy` is a deep copy function for an value object of template<typename A> . The problem is  getDataCopy() . I have not release data copy by DEALLOCATE_ARRAY . So I have found an another solution which replace the getDataCopy() function by getDataAddress in this case . many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `auto` there with pointers (assuming they are pointers and not some class with an overloaded `*` operator) is making things confusing. I think the error might be in the fact that you are creating a "copy" in `object.getDataCopy()`, returning a pointer to it and not deleting it before the return of `functions::getUserIds()`

Comment: I have tried delete or free , but it has new warning

Comment: what warning does it have? And if you allocated using the `new` operator you should call `delete` to deallocate, if you allocated memory using a C API like `malloc` only then should you call `free`

Comment: delete is warning memory allocated by malloc() , free is offset by 12 bytes from the start of memory allocated by malloc() . So I have changed the solution by using getDataAddress() and avoid getDataCopy , many thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function .getSize**s**(); implies that it returns an array of sizes?

Or it's just a bad API name.

What's the actual type of `size`?

UPDATE: the culprit is found in the comments to be the `getDataCopy()` which makes a deep copy which is then never deallocated.

Comment: the type of size is `const typename Helpers::ArrayLengthType<Etype>::type* getSizes(void) const;`  .

Comment: This is mightly overengineered API, but what if the actual culprit is not `ret` which is just a vector of value types (I assume UserId_t is an alias for uint64_t?), but actually in this line - `auto pVal = object.getDataCopy();` where you allocate a copy of data apparently but never free it. What is the type of `pVal`?

Comment: @ burkes : the type of UserID_t is uint64_t , 'getSizes' is const short *,` getDataCopy` is a deep copy function for an value object of template<typename A> . The problem is getDataCopy() . I have not release data copy by DEALLOCATE_ARRAY . So I have found an another solution which replace the getDataCopy() function by getDataAddress in this case . many thanks

Comment: I think you should accept the answer by Aaryaman Sagar, who has pointed this issue a while ago already.